# Не запускается код на питоне expected an indented block

Tags: python

Нужно проверить работу модуля random этим кодом, а он не запускается, питон кричит, что проблема в 14 строке, но что не так не понимаю
работаю в 3.5.2.3.
 сам код ниже

```
  import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
low = 12; high = 68;
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(14,5)
for k in range(3,6):
plt.subplot(1, 3, k - 2)
N = 10**k
n = range(N)
rnd = [random.uniform(low,high) for i in n]
plt.plot(n, rnd, 'b.')
plt.axis([0, N, 10 ,70])
plt.xlabel( ' $n$ ' ),
plt.ylabel( ' $rnd$ ' )
```

Comment: У вас в отступах полный бардак. В показанном вами коде ошибка есть даже в самой первой строчке

Answer (score 1):

Эта ошибка говорит о том что у тебя **проблемы с отступами**. В Python циклы(и не только) отделяются отступами. Например тело `for` нужно отделять 4 пробелами(в идеале). Я не знаю как и чо там у тебя, но думаю это будет правильно(по крайней мере ошибку это устранит)

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

low = 12
high = 68

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(14,5)

for k in range(3,6):
    plt.subplot(1, 3, k - 2)
    N = 10**k
    n = range(N)
    rnd = [random.uniform(low,high) for i in n]
    plt.plot(n, rnd, 'b.')
    plt.axis([0, N, 10 ,70])
    plt.xlabel( ' $n$ ' ),
    plt.ylabel( ' $rnd$ ' )
```

Также, точки с запятыми не нужны абсолютно, они ухудшают удобочитаемость кода. Советую почитать PEP8